# adding "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft" makes text blurry

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, styles

As soon as I add this to the css:

```
filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Strength=5, Direction=90),
         progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Strength=5, Direction=270);
```

all text inside that element gets blurry.

Is this a known problem?

Whats the work-around?

I am creating shadow effect on a div (container), and this css is applied to that div.

Also, I have tried applying position:relative and a background-color to it without any luck. Only way to get the text to look "normal" is to remove the filter so far.

Also, cleartype is disabled!

Thanks

Comment: Workaround is probably to not use an IE filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a known issue and is to do with the way these filters work. I'd recommend looking at [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/) to add this sort of behaviour - it works flawlessly for shadows and rounded corners.

Make sure you read the documentation, there are a couple of gotchas that people miss (correct mimetype for the htc, position:relative on shadowed elements).